# Default access role to users and groups in an enterprise application

Tags: azure-active-directory

How do I add default access role to users and groups in an enterprise application?

[image]

This is what I see when trying to add role manually:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created **App Roles in the Azure AD Application** like below:

[image]

Now, when ***I tried to add the user to the Enterprise Application, Default access option isn't available***:

[image]

To assign the user to the Default Access role, **I deleted the App Roles in the Azure AD Application** like below:

[image]

Now, **I am able to assign Default Access to the user successfully** like below:

[image]

[image]